# LEAP vs EAP/TLS?

Tags: security, mac-osx, wifi, eap

I am given a choice between:

- LEAP Wireless Client ID
- 802.1x (EAP/TLS) Wireless Client ID (Digital Certificates)

To connect to a wireless network.

What are the differences? Which one would you recommend I use?

I have a Macbook Pro running OS X 10.8.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use EAP/TLS. LEAP support was apparently removed from OS X with Lion. Follow the directions given by your network administrator.